# Can't compare values from my UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to output a certain number based on the first and second selection in my `UIPickerView`.  I have this code here.

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if([[list objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]] isEqual: @"1 Gallon"] && [list2 objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1] isEqual: @"Grams"])
        output.text = @"1 GALLON GRAMS";
    if([[list objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]] isEqual: @"2 Gallons"] && [list2 objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1] isEqual: @"Ounces"])
        output.text = @"2 GALLONS OUNCES";
}
```

But I keep getting an error of No visible @interface for `NSMutableArray` declares the selector `objectAtIndex:isequal`

How should I compare what the two values are returning?  Like `IF comp(0) == 3 and comp(1) ==2`, output 3.4 to my label.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because NSMutableArray doesn't have an "objectAtIndex: isEqual" selector.

You need to get the NSString from your picker view and then compare it to the string you've stored in your NSMutableArray object (which are presumably ivars named "`list`" and "`list2`").

E.G.

```
NSString * stringPointedToFromPicker = (NSString *)[list objectAtIndex: [pickerView selectedRowInComponent: 0]];
if([stringPointedToFromPicker isEqual: @"1 Gallon"]) // okay for now, but do you want
    output.text = @"1 GALLON GRAMS";        // hard coded, non-localized strings like this?
```